# Reading Assembly

Tags: assembly

I have the following two lines of assembly:

```
add    0x0(%rbp,%rbx,4),%eax
cmp    %eax,0x4(%rbp,%rbx,4)
```

I just want to make sure I am reading them correctly.
The first line is adding the contents of something and eax and then storing in eax correct?
The second line is then comparing the values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line is adding the contents of the dword stored at `(%rbp + %rbx * 4)` to what already is in `%eax`. The next line compares `%eax` to the dword stored at `(%rbp + %rbx * 4 + 4)`, i.e. the next dword in the (supposedly) array containing dwords.

Comment: So the second line is comparing the next word with the word that was just stored(from the first line)?